# Can I add my skills before checking for feat requirement?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, skills, character-advancement

So, when I level up my character in PF1, I choose a new class, add its feature, then skills and feats. But what if I want to add *Signature Skill* Feat as my level 5 feat. It requires 5 skill ranks in any given skill. But the PRD says

> When adding new levels of an existing class or adding levels of a new
> class (see Multiclassing, below), make sure to take the following
> steps in order. First, select your new class level. You must be able
> to qualify for this level before any of the following adjustments are
> made. Second, apply any ability score increases due to gaining a
> level. Third, integrate all of the level's class abilities and then
> roll for additional hit points. **Finally, add new skills and feats.**

Does the "and" means I upgrade them at the same time, or does this means I add skills, THEN feats, making me effectively having 5 skill ranks in my skill for the feat Signature Feat at level 5 ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### It is one step; you add them at the same time (but that's OK)

There are a number of Feats with Skill Point requirements and you do gain them simultaneously, but fortunately, [Feats](https://www.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx) has this information about Prerequisites:

> **Prerequisites:** Some feats have prerequisites. Your character must have the indicated ability score, class feature, feat, skill, base attack bonus, or other quality designated in order to select or use that feat. A character can gain a feat at the same level at which he gains the prerequisite.